# Visual studio 2008 - Find in files : lists everything twice

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

In VS2008, I have a web-site project. When I use find in files and search for a string, the find results window will list every occurence twice.

What could be causing this?

[EDIT]

Below is the screen capture from VS. I was searching for the work CommissionBucketProductID within my website project. Notice that each line is returned twice.

[image: Screen Capture]

[EDIT2]

In response to your questions. I am only searching within the project, not the whole solution. I currently don't have these files under VSS, although they were in the past.

Comment: Please provide an example of the search query, solution file and results returned. You haven't given enough information to figure out the problem.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I have the same problem! Everything lists twice. Like you, mine is a VS2008 web-site project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue which was annoying. I just fixed it. What I've done is to change "Entire solution" to "current project" in "Look in" field when doing search. Then I noticed the result would not be doubled. After I switched back to "entire solution" the problem was gone.

Answer (score 5):

If you do find in "Entire Solution", it also searches in any loaded files, even if they're already in the solution. This means that they'll be listed twice.

Perhaps this is your problem?

Comment: "it also searches in any loaded files" where are they loaded?

Comment: "loaded" = "open in a window in the IDE"

Comment: No, even if the file is not loaded the search results appears twice. I'm glad this was not it, because that would be really stupid :)

Answer (score 3):

I use VS2003, but I get this exact result when I have the same source file in multiple projects. Are you sure you aren't searching more than one project?

Answer (score 2):

Here's your answer:

[Find in Files searches same files twice](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/489209/find-in-files-searches-same-files-twice)

This seems to happen for files that are shared between multiple projects in the same solution, causing them to get searched twice. Since the problem exists in VS2010, it must have been inherited from VS2008, which probably means you're pretty much out of luck (unless you work around it, such as by separating the projects into multiple solutions).

But in the meantime, it sounds like it's not high enough on Microsoft's priority list to get this fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any symbolic links to a directory/file within the same search scope?  This could cause the file to be listed twice: once for the primary file, and once for the link to the file.  Although from memory it should show the directory of the link for the 2nd occurrence, not the file pointed at by the link (and this is inconsistent with what is in your screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

Try closing VS2008, renaming the file (USPostalApplciation.aspx and the code behind file too), then re-opening VS2008, refresh everything you can think of (project, solution, etc...) then try doing the search again.

Comment: This problem isn't specific to USPostalApplication.aspx. For this example, I just chose a search term that was only found in that page. If I search for "page_load" or some common term, every page (and there are over a 100) in the project will show up twice.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your web project does NOT have any virtual directories that point back to other areas of the site.

Verify that VS2008 shows the same virtual directories (if any) that IIS has.

If you have mis-pointed or mis-configured Virtual directories, it will cause a HUGE performance hit, search result replication, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. VS would turn up find solution results from files I had loaded in the IDE just to view them and then closed again. So it would search through files that weren't even in the solution.

I scanned all files in the solution, but there was no reference to these phantom files stored anywhere. Finally I decided to scan the registry and found that they were stored in the MRU list. After deleting the MRU list entries, the expected behavior was restored.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but this still happens.

As new info, I just found that the solution contains a Setup project, which naturally references some of the projects, besides the solution itself.

In that case, when searching the Entire Solution there are two routes to some files.

Answer (score 0):

In the **"Look in"** field of the **"Find and Replace"** dialog box, make sure that the folder to be scanned is listed only once.
You can list multiple folders, separated by commas.
If a folder is listed twice, you will get twice the result!